# Mobile localisation app based on kml layers

Tags: google-maps, localization, cordova, kml, layer

I'm trying to develop a mobile app that locates the nearest location. I'm using Phonegap, Google Maps API v3, and KML layers to show the locations.  I came up with this workflow:
1. The main view contains an autocomplete search box , so that once the user starts a search:

1. The query is sent to a service that will filter and generate a KML file for the results.
   So here I am not using Google Maps Distance API; the service will retrieve the user's lat and long and then generate KML files which will contain the user's location and sorted matching results.
2. Finally we use the KML file with Google Maps for rendering the results.

Is this the right way to go about doing things? 
Or is the Google Maps Distance API more accurate than manually calculate the distance using some maths? 
Thank u in advance.

Comment: the DistanceMatrix-API returns results based on routes, how would you calculate this by using some maths(without knowing the routes)

Comment: Im not showing routes , basically i wanna show only markers not routes , and im targeting a small city so im basically doing this to calculate the distance http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I'm not talking about showing routes, with a simple calculation you may only get a linear distance, while the DistanceMatrixService returns the travel distance